# Numerically stable Angle bisector algorithm

Tags: c++, math

Is there any numerically stable angle bisector algorithm?

**The problem is the following:**

- Given three vectors (2 dimensional) A,B,C
- Find the bisector of angle B (angle between AB and BC)

Actually I'm computing it in the following way:

- Normalize AB
- Normalize BC
- Find (AB+CD)/2f (Mid Point)
- **The bisector** is line passing between B and the Mid Point.

The problem with my approach is that when the angle is almost 180° (AB almost parallel to BC) the bisector is very inaccurate (of course because mid point is almost coincident with B). The current algorithm is so inaccurate that sometimes the resulting bisector is almost parallel to one of the other 2 segments.

And yes there are no "cast" problems, all computations are done in single precision floating point.

Comment: Hint: try to build the bisector with compass and straightedge. Pretend that you've lost your eyeglasses and cannot separate points which are very close to each other.

Comment: which is exactly what I'm already doing ^^. The algorithm I'm using is using 2 unitary circles, eventually I'm asking how to make it numerically stable, or to provide an alternative stable variant.

Comment: The paper/compass algorithm requires 2 vectors of same lenght. In the case I make them longer, the problem still persists when starting vectors are short.

Comment: "which is exactly what I'm already doing" You are (1) connecting two points, (2) find the midpoint of the resulting segment, and (3) draw a line through the midpoint and another point which may lie arbitrarily close to it. A bisector can be built in a much simpler way. Don't start with (1).

Comment: "the problem still persists when starting vectors are short" You can scale the construction before you start solving the problem as much as you like. Floating point numbers are well suited to that. It's subtraction of two very close numbers which is problematic.

Comment: You should try to have a clear notation. It would help answers, but most likely it would help *you* in getting it yourself. You use "B" for three different things, as a point, as a angle, and as a vector. There is no one definite standard notation, but "B" for point, "AB" for the line segment linking the points A and B, \(\overrightarrow{AB}\) for vector from A to B, \(\widehat{ABC}\) for the angle between AB and BC, or simply \(\hat{B}\) if it is not ambiguous, is common notation. Or whatever :-) but avoid using the same symbol for different concepts. (edit: oh, LaTeX not active here...)

Comment: It is already like that the notation. I don't understand what you mean _-_ and apart that every item was commented to explain what was that. When I Say B It Is a point. AB Is a segment between points A and B. Its clear, Maybe it was not elegant but that's another story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not trivial. Let’s say the two edge vectors are a and b:

```
float2 a = A - B;
float2 b = C - B;
```

1. Compute the dot product `float dp = dot( a, b )`
2. Normalize both vectors:

```
float2 a_norm = normalize( a );
float2 b_norm = normalize( b );
```

3. Check the sign bit of the dot product. When the `dp` is non-negative,
   `return normalize( a_norm + b_norm );` and you’re done.
4. When the dot product is negative, you have obtuse angle between input vectors.
   Applying a naïve formula in this case would screw up the numerical precision.
   Need another way.

```
float2 c = normalize( a_norm - b_norm );
float dir = dot( a, rotate90( b ) );
return ( dir < 0 ) ? rotate90( c ) : rotate270( c );
```

Note `-` instead of the `+`, this is what gives the precision win. When the angle between `a` and `b` is greater than 90°, the angle between `a` and `-b` is less than 90°, and the length of `a_norm - b_norm` is large enough to give accurate direction. We just need to rotate it by 90° afterwards, in the correct direction.

P.S. Rotating 2D vectors by multiples of 90° is lossless operation.
Here’s pseudocode for rotate90 and rotate270 functions:

```
float2 rotate90( float2 vec )
{
    return float2( vec.y, -vec.x );
}
float2 rotate270( float2 vec )
{
    return float2( -vec.y, vec.x );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally a stable algorithm.

Comment: @CoffeDeveloper See the update, I’ve normalized it twice by mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use that the angle bisector remains the same if you rotate BA by +90° and BC by -90°.

So use the original formula if the situation is stable, that is, if the dot product of BA and BC is positive.

If it is negative, apply the rotations, for BA `(x,y) -> (-y,x)` and for `BC` `(x,y) -> (y,-x)`, which also renders the dot product positive. Proceed as before with the new vectors.

If you try this out you will note that the jump in direction of the bisector now occurs for the angle -90° between the vectors. It is not possible to avoid this jump, as a continuous bisector will only be the same after two turns (fixing BA and moving C).

Answer (score 1):

A simple enough way to do this follows in two formats (but the content is otherwise identical):

### Pseudocode

```
// Move A and C to the origin for easier rotation calculations
Aprime=A-B;
Cprime=C-B;
// The counter-clockwise angle between the positive X axis to A'
angle_a = arctan(Aprime.y, Aprimet.x);
// ditto for C'
angle_c = arctan(Cprime.y, Cprime.x);
// The counter-clockwise angle from A' to C'
angle_ac = angle_c - angle_a;
// The counter-clockwise angle from the positive X axis to M'
angle_m = angle_ac/2 + angle_a;
// Construct M' which, like A' and C', is relative to the origin.
Mprime=(cos(angle_m), sin(angle_m));
// Construct M which is relative to B rather than relative to the origin.
M=Mprime+B
```

### In English

1. Move the vectors to the origin by

   - `A'=A-B`
   - `B'=B`
   - `C'=C-B`
2. Get the angle from the positive X axis to `A'` as `angle_a = arctan(A_y, A_x)`.
3. Get the angle from the positive X axis to `C'` as `angle_c = arctan(C_y, C_x)`.
4. Get the counter-clockwise angle from `A'` to `C'` as `angle_ac = angle_c - angle_a`.
5. Get the angle from the positive X axis to `M'` as `angle_m = angle_ac/2 + angle_a`.
6. Construct `M'` from this angle as `M' = (cos(angle_m), sin(angle_m))`.
7. Construct `M` as `M = M' + B`.

The vector `BM` bisects the angle `ABC`.

Since there is arbitrary division, there are no difficulties with this method. Here's a graphing calculator to encourage intuition with the solution: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwbno717da

Answer (score 0):

You can find the bisecting vector quite simply with:

```
∥BC∥ * BA + ∥BA∥ * BC
```

But that also won't be numerically stable with ABC collinear or nearly so.  What might work better would be to find the angle between AB and BC, via the dot product.

```
cos θ = (BA · BC) / (∥BC∥ * ∥BA∥)
```

That will produce the correct angle even in the collinear case.

Comment: This is a very concise answer, but I'm not quite sure I understand. `|BC|` is the length of the vector, `C-B`, but what is `AB`? Is that the vector from `A` to `B` (`B-A`)?

Comment: The original question was a bit off in its terminology; addressed in some of the other answers.  `A`, `B`, `C` can be considered points, with `AB` denoting the vector from point `A` to point `B`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I considered that, but it doesn't look correct. Given A(0.2,0), B(0,0), and C(0, 2), I would expect a bisecting vector to be along the line y=x, but using your formula, I get the point (-2,0.2). (`∥BC∥=2, AB=(-0.2,0), ∥AB∥=0.2, BC=(0,2)`.) What am I missing?

Comment: I see the problem, the first vector should be `BA`.  The question is finding the angle bisector, so the two vectors must have a common mid-point, in this case `B`.

Comment: So if we follow the math, `∥BC∥ * BA = (0.4, 0)` and `∥BA∥ * BC = (0, 0.4)`, and then their sum is `(0.4, 0.4)`.  The vector from `B` to `(0.4, 0.4)` will bisect the angle.  And it does, as the angle is obviously 90° and the bisector is clearly 45°.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Better now!

Comment: This has the same problem of not being stable near 180 degrees and gives a zero result for a negative vector at exactly 180 degrees

Comment: Are you saying that the formula I said "won't be numerically stable with ABC collinear of nearly so,"  won't be stable near 180 degrees?  I believe I covered that.  Or are you saying that that the format which I said would be stable is not?  If the latter, do you have an example?

Answer (score -1):

**Definition:** If A and B are points, vector(A,B) is the vector from point A to B.

Lets say that point O is the point of origin for our coordinate system.

The **coordinates of point A** are the **same** as of **radius-vector(O,A).**

Let point M be the middle point for the bisector,so you need to:

-normalize  vector(B,A)

-normalize  vector(B,C)

-vector(B,M) = vector(B,A)+vector(B,C) //vector from B to middle point

-(optionally) You can multiply vector(B,M) with a scalar to get a longer vector / increase distance between B and M

-vector(O,M) = vector(O,B) + vector(B,M)//radius-vector from O to M

Now middle point M has the same coordinates as radius-vector(O,M).